# Handling HttpRequestValidationException ASP.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, validation, httprequest

This is my first time doing a project in ASP so this is my first time running into the dreaded A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client... error.

I've looked around the web and stackoverflow, and can't seem to find a "best practice" way to deal with this. I don't exactly want to turn off all validations, because that would mean that in every single text box where the user can input data, I need to have to encode/decode the text myself right? Which leads me to think that this is a very easy way to leave security holes in your site.

Another seemingly common fix is to have the validation break gracefully and lead to a nicer looking error page for the user, which isn't a bad fix, but it can't be the best right?

I've noticed on most sites, if you enter the HTML encoding for a apostrophe for example, it automatically turns into a apostrophe character. As I type this now, if I try to type in &#39 ; (take away the space between 9 and ; and this is the HTML encoding for apostrophe), it automatically gets converted into a '. There has to be a way in ASP.net 4.0 to do the same thing?

Btw, I'm using c# as my backend server side code.

Comment: I started to investigate this a couple of weeks ago. All I found was to turn validation off. Yes, that didn't seem very satisfying to me either so I welcome any answers to this.